# Installing tcpdump breaks IPv4 networking?

Tags: ethernet, raspbian-jessie, dhcpcd

On a Raspberry Pi 2 running Jessie, I just installed tcpdump. It worked when installing, but after rebooting, IPv4 is unavailable on the eth0 interface. It is normally headless and reached by SSH, but now I can only access with the HDMI screen and USB keyboard.

Using [this article](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os/37921#37921) I set up a Fallback Profile by editing `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.
Still eth0 is not available on ipv4.

After boot, it reports eth0 is down, but I can bring it up with `ifconfig eth0 up`, but neither DHCP nor the Fallback Profile are used.

Is this related to tcpdump, or another random failure?

Edit: It was difficult to share any information with only the HDMI screen. I was able to connect with SSH using the ipv6 global unicast address, so now I can share more details:

Whenever the Pi boots it starts with eth0 down.

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:9c:03:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 10  bytes 1582 (1.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 1582 (1.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have to use `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` to enable it.

Then I see this:

```
 $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:9c:03:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 26**:a**1:a**8:300:ba27:ebff:fe9c:3bf/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe9c:3bf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I am then able to connect SSH via the ipv6 global unicast address.

Here is the dhcpcd.conf file:

```
 $ cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
profile static_eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.177/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
interface eth0
fallback static_eth0
```

This is a strange situation, because the system had been working fine. The only changes made were installing tcpdump, and uncommenting the `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in /boot/config.txt so the monitor would always be active. As part of debugging I also enabled the fallback to static profile in dhcpcd.conf, which had no effect, likely indicating the failure is other than the DHCP server.

Edit2:

I used `journelctl --unit=dhcpcd` and found this:

```
-- Boot 9abf20c43bdd4929b2c8b2175e4505bd --
Apr 16 15:30:24 Pi2-TG11 systemd[1]: Starting DHCP Client Daemon...
Apr 16 15:30:24 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[347]: dev: loaded udev
Apr 16 15:30:25 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[347]: no valid interfaces found
Apr 16 15:30:25 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[347]: no valid interfaces found
Apr 16 15:30:25 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[347]: forked to background, child pid 421
Apr 16 15:30:25 Pi2-TG11 systemd[1]: Started DHCP Client Daemon.
Apr 16 15:40:26 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[421]: received SIGTERM, stopping
Apr 16 15:40:26 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[421]: dhcpcd exited
Apr 16 15:40:26 Pi2-TG11 systemd[1]: Stopping DHCP Client Daemon...
Apr 16 15:40:26 Pi2-TG11 systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Succeeded.
Apr 16 15:40:26 Pi2-TG11 systemd[1]: Stopped DHCP Client Daemon.
```

for a prior boot, it looked like this:

```
-- Boot 5d7aad0b1a6846c88d6f261b97d00bb0 --
Feb 22 18:42:36 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[333]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Feb 22 18:42:38 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[333]: eth0: carrier acquired
Feb 22 18:42:38 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[333]: DUID 00:01:00:01:29:86:02:09:b8:27:eb:9c:03:bf
Feb 22 18:42:38 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[333]: eth0: IAID eb:9c:03:bf
Feb 22 18:42:38 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[333]: eth0: adding address fe80::1fae:fbde:b8f8:504
Feb 22 18:42:39 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[333]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Feb 22 18:42:39 Pi2-TG11 dhcpcd[333]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.177
```

So why would dhcpcd start to see "no valid interfaces"?

Comment: It's certainly not normal.  You might as well approach the problem as if it could have been anything, because I don't see how considering tcpdump will provide any concrete starting place.  *"ip a shows two ipv6 addresses"* -> Presumably this don't mean anything to you, but you might as well post them explicitly as they might provide a clue.  *"it reports eth0 is down"* -> Again, you should include information verbatim as well as your interpretation -- eg. [there are several places that may say up or down in ip command output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123918/5538).

Comment: See edits with more information I was able to obtain by connecting SSH over ipv6

Comment: Additional edit with findings from journelctl - apparently eth0 is no longer valid for dhcpcd?

Comment: `jessie` is quite old now (2015), and IIRC it was the first version to come with `dhcpcd` (aka `dhcpcd5`). I wonder if you might not be better off trying to install a more up-to-date version of `dhcpcd`?

Comment: Another thought is to try setting up a static configuration in `dhcpcd.conf`  - i.e. no fallback configuration; just make a normal static config. At least that should keep `dhcpcd` out of it. Obviously that will require the static config be set up correctly. Make sure this works before enabling `tcpdump`. IOW - try to eliminate as many variables as possible.

Comment: Also recall that setting a static IP may require you to make some config changes in your gateway/dhcp server/whatever.

Comment: BTW, if you are hoping to use tcpdump to sniff WLAN traffic on a router you are connected to via ethernet cable, it probably will not work; none of the WLAN packets will be directed your way unless they are intended for your address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WRT dhcpcd, I don't have a direct solution, but you could try stopping the service and seeing if you can set eth up using the somewhat simpler `dhclient`:

```
sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd
sudo ip link set eth0 up
sudo dhclient -v eth0
```

The auto configuration that's happening with the two IPv6 addresses, the `mngtmpaddr` one and the link local one (`fe80::`) probably won't interfere with this, but if so you can remove them with `ip addr`.

If `dhclient` isn't installed, the package is `isc-dhcp-client`.  It's configuration should work out of the box.  It provides a bit of initial feedback when started and forks into the background when a lease is acquired.
It logs directly to syslog once backgrounded.

If that works, unfortunately there is no ready made systemd service but arranging something should be simple enough:

```
[Unit]
Description=DHCP on eth0
Requires=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=no
StandardInput=null
ExecStart=/sbin/dhclient -v eth0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I've used pretty much that to automate `dhclient` before.
Name that what you like with a `.service` suffix, put it in `/etc/systemd/system/` and `sudo systemd enable whatyoulike.service`.
It will then start automatically at boot and via `systemctl start whatyoulike`.  You will be able to get feedback about the current state via `systemctl status whatyoulike` and a record of the output (the lease negotiation stuff `dhclient` prints before it forks into the background) for previous runs (depending how journalling is configured) with `sudo journalctl -xeu whatyoulike`).

**Also make sure you add:**

```
denyinterfaces eth0
```

To `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` (and if you have no purpose for it, `sudo systemd disable dhcpcd`).

Comment: Thank you! That does work. The eth0 interface acquired the IPv4 address from DHCP after the `sudo dhclient -v eth0` command. Apparently dhclient is still installed since it worked correctly. Now how can I restore the original behavior where the DCHP client ran automatically during boot?  This is supposed to be a headless system, so connecting a USB keyboard and HDMI monitor whenever it boots is not ideal. I still don't understand what changed to cause this failure?

Comment: If dhclient works you might as well stick with it, I've added a means above.